# Store row from matrix to column in another matrix by indexes vector

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing

Assume that I have the matrix A, zero matrix B and indices vectors i,idx:

```
A = np.array([[1, 1, 2], [0, 0, 1]])
B = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]])
i = np.arange(len(idx))    
idx = np.array([1, 0])
```

By `i` and `idx` I know that I need to store the **0 row of A into the 1 column of B** because:

```
i = [0, 1]  #Rows at A
idx = [1, 0] # Columns at B
```

I need the matrix `B` to be:

```
B =
0 1 
0 1
1 2
```

I tried:

```
B[:, idx] = A[i, :]
```

and it didn't work.
Can someone help?

thanks!
Nofar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close in your proposed solution:

```
B[:,idx] = A[i,:].T
```